# how do I create a generic oauth 2.0 authentication provider for DotNetNuke?

Tags: authentication, azure, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN installation, I need to Use the APP endpoints from windows Azure active directory which are restful oauth2.0 or saml. I can't find a module that will authenticate this way so I guess I need to create my own authentication provider. However the documentation on this seems very out of date no mater where I look. I've seen christoc's templates for DNN modules in VS2013 but I don't think that's for authentication providers.

can I simply copy the current login provider somehow and add the functionality? If so will it respond correctly to callbacks with tokens etc..?

In the end I'd like the users of one site to login and later come to this site and already be logged in with the same SSO account.

I can work with a general step 1-2-3 explanation I'm just not sure what the right way to go abouyt the DNN part is.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an authentication module for WAAD you will need to build your own Authentication provider.  There are 4 OAuth providers which are included in the later DNN releases.  I would copy the Windows Live provider and make the modifications necessary to make it work with WAAD.

You can find the source code for the Authentication providers in the /DNN Platform/Providers/Authentication folder in the source code version of DNN which is available from [dotnetnuke.codeplex.com](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was a source code version. That helps a lot lol.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently created an **open source Azure Active Directory authentication provider for DNN Platform** that uses the OAuth2 webflow pattern. The provider itself and the source code is available at https://github.com/davidjrh/dnn.azureadprovider

Hope this helps.